# Count the integer array values Android

Tags: android, arrays

I have an integer array for example

```
int[] abc = {123, 100};
```

and I want to count its value, like `123 + 100` etc, how can I apply it to my code ?

Answer (score 3):

Am assuming you want to sum up the content of your array. If so then try:

```
 int sum = 0;
 for (int i= 0; i < abc.length; i++) {
     sum += abc[i];
 }
 System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: ah your answer is just count the length of array.. still can't sum up the content/value of the array

Answer (score 1):

```
  int[] abc = {123, 100};
    int value=0;
    for(int i=0; i<abc.length; i++){           
        int x =(int) Array.get(abc, i);
        value=value+x;
      }       
      System.out.println(value);
```

**Updates**

Explanations:

In order to get the total value of the array you need to loop inside the array. So in my case I use **for** loop, abc.length is method to get the length of the whole array and so helps us to interact with all element inside the array.

I am assigning each element of an array to variable **x** in each difference loop. **Array.get(abc, i)** here we are using get method of Array class to get a specific element of array in index **i** that we assign to **x**.

Final we had each element of the array to a variable **value** in every interaction, The last interaction will be our summation of all elements of our array.

Hope this helps,Sorry for my English.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 1):

Just use the advance loop for this:

```
         int sum = 0;
        for (int i : abc) {
            sum += i;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: here abc is your int array like:  int[] abc = {123, 100};

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the summary of an integer array:

- Declare a summary variable with `0` as init value.
- Go through each element in the array, then add its value to the summary variable

**Solution 1:** Using traditional for loop

```
int[] abc = {123, 100};

int arrayLength = abc.length;
int arraySum = 0;
for (int arrayIndex = 0; arrayIndex < arrayLength; arrayIndex++) {
    int value = abc[arrayIndex];
    arraySum = arraySum + value;
}
```

**Solution 2:** Using enhanced for loop (available from Java 5)

```
int[] abc = {123, 100};

int arraySum = 0;
for (int value : abc) {
    arraySum = arraySum + value;
}
```

**Solution 3:** Using [Stream](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/stream/package-summary) API (required Java 8 and API level 24)

```
int arraySum = Arrays.stream(abc).sum();
```

In your app, you might need to calculate the summary of an integer array in many places, so you can create a method and use it everywhere you need.

```
public int calculateSum(int[] array) {
    int arraySum = 0;
    for (int value : array) {
        arraySum = arraySum + value;
    }
    return arraySum;
}
```

Use the method

```
int[] abc = {123, 100};

int arraySum = calculateSum(abc);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be better ways to calculate the sum of the elements in a List in Java than this, below shows the source code for a Java “sum the integers in a list”:

```
    int[] abc = {123, 100};
    
    int sum = 0;
    for (int value : abc) {
        sum = sum + value; // or can be; sum += value;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
```

**Note** that one thing you have to be careful with in an algorithm like this is that if you’re working with very large numbers, the sum of a list of integers may end up being a long value. I assume you are just adding small number of int (As most “sum” algorithms don’t account for this, but I thought I should mention it.)